# subprocess check_output throws exception without any error message

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run `clang main.cpp -o myprogram.exe` in the terminal I get a meaningful error message:

```
main.cpp:6:32: error: expected ';' after expression
    std::cout << "Hello World!"
```

but when I try to reproduce it using python and running

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('clang main.cpp -o myprogram.exe')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.output)
    print(e.stderr)
    print(e.stdout)
```

```
Command 'clang main.cpp -o myprogram.exe' returned non-zero exit status 1.
b''
None
b''
```

How can I give my user back the same error message the terminal provides?

Comment: It's perfectly legal for a tool to check whether output is to a TTY and change its logging configuration based on the result. Not asserting that clang is doing this, or that it isn't, but as a general note.

Comment: If in bash -- without Python being involved at all -- you run `clang main.cpp -o myprogram.exe 2> >(cat)`, do you get similar behavior?

Comment: ...that said, it's a serious code smell that you aren't using `shell=True` or splitting the command into words (ideally, specifying it as a list in the first place, f/e `['clang', 'main.cpp', '-o', 'myprogram.exe']`). You should be getting a completely different error (specifically, one saying that no executable named `clang main.cpp -o myprogram.exe` exists) if you're on a reasonable/sane/UNIXlike operating system; and if you _aren't_ on a normal OS but are instead using something bizarre like Windows, that detail should be included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), `subprocess.check_output(...)` is equivalent to `subprocess.run(..., check=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout`, which means that `subprocess.check_output(...)` is getting your **standard output** by default, but your command is returning an exit code 1, which means error, so the command output will be captured by **standard error**, and I'm surprised that your `e.stderr` isn't working, but as a workaround you can capture the **standard error** in the **standard output** using `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, like this:

```py
subprocess.check_output(
    "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True
)
```

Again, this comes from the Python docs referenced before.

#### Update 1:

To get `e.stderr` to work, you must use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, so the following should work:

```py
try:
    subprocess.check_output(
        ['clang', 'main.cpp', '-o', 'myprogram.exe'],
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.stderr)
```

Note that it is preferable to use a list to provide the command args (as stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673440/subprocess-check-output-throws-exception-without-any-error-message#comment135179776_76673440)).